# PHP mail sends but sender is always "Apache <apache@hosting12"

Tags: php, email, sender

In my mail client or gmail the sender is always apache@hosting12

Any way to fix this issue? 
I have tried setting the headers like these with no success. Can sombody please help me?

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <'$from'> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <'$from'> \r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: <'$from'>\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
```

or

```
$headers = "From: $from";
```

Comment: Please see my answer regarding `php.ini` file where you can set `sendfrom_mail` option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove single quotation mark from around `$from` and use `{$from}`

```
$headers .= 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>' . "\r\n";
```

or you can use following signatures to pass `from`

```
mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

**EDIT:**

You also want to check `sendmail_from` setting in `php.ini` file.

Comment: Still the same problem. Emails go to junk folder and gmail thinks they are spam. sender is always as apache@hosting12

Comment: Then you should use SMTP email instead of mail function. I think this article may help you: http://www.9lessons.info/2009/10/send-mail-using-smtp-and-php.html

Answer (score 8):

I found that answer on a french forum.
http://www.developpez.net/forums/d413965/php/outils/configuration-sendmail_path-sender/

You can add a 5th param to the mail function:

```
mail($mail_recipient, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f'.$mail_from);
```

Ths '-f' + mail_from force the system to send the email as the mail_from.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, you would need this if you want to relay email to mailgun.

Answer (score 4):

There are extra single quotes in your header. Try like this:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: <$from> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <$from> \r\n";
$headers .= "Return-Path: <$from>\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";
```

Also you can remove the unnecessary "Reply-To" and "Return-Path".

Comment: still the same. I think it has something to do with my hosting provider?